# ios7 Getting Delegate for canDisplayBannerAds

Tags: ios7, iad

I am integrating iAd with AdMob. I want to call AdMob when iAd fails to deliver an ad.  The problem I am encountering is that the basic `canDisplayBannerAds = YES` does not fire a delegate method when ads fail to load.  If I were actually creating a banner ad I could set that delegate to self.  However, here since all we have to do is call `self.canDisplayBannerAds = YES;` I don't understand where to set the delegate.  The method for failure is:

`- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error`

However, the above is not called when iAd cannot deliver (I have the simulator set to always fail).  I do have `ADBannerViewDelegate` set in the interface.

Do I need to actually create a banner myself to get access to this delegate and method or is there someway to get the delegate working here so that I can use the above method?

Comment: After using some other search terms I came across some information on this.  It would appear that I cannot use this simplified method to do what I want and that I have to create the ad the old way in order to get the delegate.  If I am wrong someone can chime in here.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but at a certain point in your app you can check your view controller's `displayingBannerAd` boolean to see if an iAd is currently being displayed. If not, show your AdMob ads...

Comment: Thanks for your response.  The problem with that approach is that I have to purposely carve out time at regular intervals to check.  Ads can come and go at will so being notified when it happens is far preferable.  I wound just implementing it the "long form" way which gives me access to the delegate.

Comment: @C6Silver No problem, just thought I'd give you a suggestion. Good luck!